# How do I pass an angle bracket ("<") to IO.popen in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This command works fine when using backticks to make a system call:

`aspell -a < /path/textfile`

However, if I try this it does not work:

```
result = IO.popen(["aspell", "-a", "<", "/path/textfile"]).read
```

It seems to be an issue with the angle bracket, because this works fine:

```
result = IO.popen([ "aspell", "--help"]).read
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't. It's not a part of the command line, it's a shell feature. Why do you need it? Why not just give the filename to aspell?

Comment: How do I do that? `aspell -a /path/file` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Drop the -a and just give the filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a shell operation, and as `popen` is interfacing directly with your command, you can't do it. Instead you assume the responsibility for doing this, which is why the `Open3` library exists and things like the [`popen2`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen2) method in particular:

Adapting your code:

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen2('aspell', '-a') do |stdin, stdout, wait_thr|
  # Feed the contents of /path/textfile into the STDIN of this
  # subprocess.
  stdin.write(File.read('/path/textfile'))
  stdin.close

  # Read the results back
  result = stdout.read
end
```

This might be advantageous since you no longer need to write to a temporary file to do operations like this, you can just feed in data directly through the `stdin` pipe.